# LEFT join AND command in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

I want to write a query in yii2
and i dont know how to write it
i tried few things from documentaion but its not working
here is my query

```
SELECT notification.*,event.title,user.firstname,user.lastname FROM notification 
LEFT JOIN event ON event.id = notification.source_id 
AND notification.activity_type = "checkin"
Where user.firstname in (select id from user where user_id=1) 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = notification.source_id 
AND notification.activity_type = "friend" 
Where user.firstname in (select id from user where user_id=1)
```

and here is the query i write for now,i need to add AND function just like its in the query

```
    $query  ->select(['notification.*,event.title,user.firstname,user.lastname'])
            ->from('notification')
            ->leftJoin('event', 'event.id = notification.source_id')
            ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id = notification.source_id');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
$query  ->select(['notification.*,event.title,user.firstname,user.lastname'])
            ->from('notification')
            ->leftJoin('event', 'event.id = notification.source_id AND notification.activity_type = "checkin" ')
            ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id = notification.source_id AND notification.activity_type = "friend"');
```

Comment: thank you for your replay.. its still having some problem but i got the idea and can figure that out..

Comment: do you know how to write `where user_id in (subquery)` in yii2... i want to include where condition in the same `$query`... updated the question